Minimum numbers of operation required to make an array bitonic
I am trying to solve this code challenge:

Given an array arr of n integers, in a single operation, one can reduce any element of the array by 1.  Find the minimum number of operations required to make the array a bitonic* array.
* A bitonic array can have any number of zeros in prefix and suffix. The non-zero part should increase from 1 to some integer k and then decrease to 1.
Example of a bitonic array: [0,1,2,3,2,1,0,0].
Example 1
Input: [3,3,3,3,3]
Answer: 6 (Final Array: [1,2,3,2,1])
Example 2
Input: [1,1,3,1,1]
Answer: 3 (Final Array: [0,1,2,1,0])
Example 3:
Input: [1,2,1,3,2]
Answer: 5 (Final Array: [1,2,1,0,0] or [0,0,1,2,1])

I can see a brute force solution as follows:

Set the minimum to Infinity
For each index in arr:

For each value in the range 0 up to arr[index]:

Create a bitonic array with arr[index] = value being the peak.
If this is possible, AND it can be formed by only making reductions from arr:

Calculate the number of reductions needed
If this number of reductions is less than minimum:

update minimum to this result








Return minimum

But this has a bad time complexity, giving unacceptable running times for large inputs. Is there an efficient algorithm for this?

Not a homework question. Got this question in Amazon interview. Not able to solve it. Couldn't find similar question anywhere. So any help would be appreciated.

Did you search for make an array bitonic ? Does this help? Arrays: Find minimum number of swaps to make bitonicity of array minimum?

@abra the operation allowed is not the same. I doubt that link would solve this problem.

@systummm We cannot help you if we don't know where you are stuck. Take time to tackle the problem by yourself, edit your question with what you've tried and where it does not work. Currently this question is not suitable (there isn't really a question), but it's close.

@AloisChristen "We cannot help you if we don't know where you are stuck" - That's actually rarely relevant for an algorithm question. Seeing an attempt entirely off the mark does not do much for anyone.

This can be done with linear time complexity:
Get the sum of all the values in the array.
Perform a forward sweep through the array making the necessary reductions to ensure that a value is never greater than one more than its (possibly already updated) predecessor. The predecessor value of the very first element should be taken as 0.
On the updated array, repeat the same operation in the reversed direction.
After these two steps we have performed the minimum reductions needed to get an array whose elements are never greater than either neighbor plus 1, again taking 0 for a neighbor value when there is no neighbor.
Find the greatest value in this array, which will become the peak of the bitonic array. If there are multiple positions to choose from, it doesn't matter as the final sum of the bitonic array will be the same: the number of operations to achieve it is the difference between the original array's sum and the final array's sum.
The final array sum is the peak value squared -- it is not necessary to actually make the array bitonic. For instance, if the peak value is 3, then the sum of the values in the bitonic array will be 1+2+3+2+1 = 9.
Here is an implementation in a runnable JavaScript snippet, running the three examples you have given:


function makeBitonic(arr) {
    // Get sum of input array's values
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) sum += arr[i];
    // Sweep forward and backward, clipping the array so two neighboring values 
    //   never differ by more than 1, and the outer values are never more than 1.
    for (let sweep = 0; sweep < 2; sweep++) {
        let max = 0; // Maximum value allowed in array element
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            max++; // Allow one more than previous limit
            if (arr[i] > max) {
                arr[i] = max;  // clip
            } else {
                max = arr[i];
            }
        }
        arr.reverse(); // Prepare for the reverse sweep
    }
    let m = Math.max(...arr);
    return sum - m * m; // m² is final sum
}

const tests = [
    [[3,3,3,3,3], 6],
    [[1,1,3,1,1], 3],
    [[1,2,1,3,2], 5],
    [[9,9,0,9,9], 35],
];

for (const [arr, expected] of tests) {
    console.log("Test: ", JSON.stringify(arr), "expect", expected);
    const got = makeBitonic(arr);
    if (got != expected) throw "Wrong result, got " + got;
}




Very clean and concise answer. +1
